# Computer property not refreshing "sometimes" - force reload?- Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building a masonry grid using Vue.js. It is working really well, except in some odd cases. When the screen re-sizes, it needs to re-compute widths/heights/paddings, etc.

However, occasionally, things get weirdly out of sync, which breaks the design.

See the screenshot below showing the data that is out of sync. I have highlighted the padding-right evaluation specifically, but it's also happening with width.

This is never happening on page load, only when the page is re-sized and re-calculated.

Is there a way to force a Vue JS component to refresh it's computed properties? It seems like that is the problem here, but not sure.

Here is the computed property code.

```js
imageStyleObject: function () {
    return {
        width: this.image.width + 'px',
        height: this.height + 'px',
        paddingRight: this.image.padding_right + 'px',
    }
},
```

```html
<div class="masonry-image-container" :style="imageStyleObject">
    <a @click.stop="imageSelected">
        <img :src="imagePath" :alt="image.description" :style="styleObject">
    </a>
</div>
```

Updated with how

```html
<masonry-image v-for="image in row.images" :key="image.id" :image="image" :height="row.height"></masonry-image>
```

[image]

Comment: How do you set value for `this.image`?

Comment: It's a prop passed in from looping through the images within an ImageRow....

<masonry-image v-for="image in row.images" :key="image.id" :image="image" :height="row.height"></masonry-image>

Comment: Can you please show us the whole component so we can get a better understanding how your code works?

If any of the variables that you are referencing in your computed property isn't reactive, the computed property will not work properly.